# Multiple cookie options - ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Identity 2.0. I would like to set up two different cookie options.
For example:

If the user logs in with the "Keep me logged in" **checked**:

- Expire in 30 days
- No sliding window

If the user logs in with the "Keep me logged in" **unchecked**:

- Expire in 1 hour
- Sliding window

I can set these values in my Startup class by setting the options on CookieAuthenticationOptions, but I must choose only one value.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but I suspect you might be able to change the options in the events based on your check boxes if you can flow the info to the middleware callbacks.

I.e. hook something like OnResponseSignIn on the CookieAuthenticationProvider and in there modify the CookieAuthenticationOptions in the context.  The hard part will be flowing the check box value into this callback.

As an FYI: normally we just use the AuthenticatiationProperties.IsPersistent flag to toggle between similar modes.